# How to set the response header's Cache-Control in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

By default, it looks like Sitecore does not cache pages. In web.config, set this

```
<setting name="DisableBrowserCaching" value="false"/>
```

and create pipeline processor

```
page.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60));
page.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
```

but it did not work, the response head stays `no-cache`. By the way, I add the pipeline in the `renderLayout`, anyone knows? thanks!

Comment: What version of Sitecore are you using?

Answer (score 3):

I have tried to reproduce this by first setting the `DisableBrowserCaching` setting to `true`. This will indeed produce a no-cache header.

Then i've set it to `false` and reloaded the page and the no-cache header disappeared. There was no need for anything else.

If you want to set expiry headers, you should do this in IIS, in the HTTP Response Headers feature.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out. There was <%@ OutputCache Location="None" VaryByParam="none" %> in the layout.aspx. That's why the API didn't work. Gotta remove it first!

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore has 7 layers of caching before the content is rendered as HTML. You can control the caching on every before the contents is rendered. But it's true that no-cache is true by default.

This is because pages in Sitecore are dynamic. They change layout and contents depending on the current situation. Expecially if you use devices ( http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2012/04/12/identifying-mobile-devices-in-sitecore/ ) and when using the Sitecore DMS, content is rendered differently for each devices and user.

If you build your own browser-caching mechanisms, please be sure that you only do this on pages with static content.